# Unable to open Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide, vs-community-edition

[image]

As shown in the image. I am not able to open VS 2013 CE. If I click the link, it just opens a new instance of VS2013 with the same dialog window. So I am not able to click the Sign In link at the upper right corner of the main window. And if I click the Close button, the whole app closes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't click on the HELP menu to get to the "Register Product" option, as the message box won't let you click on anything else.

My next suggestion is to try to Repair the product.

Go to Control Panel > Programs and Features > Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013 > Repair  (it's one of the options). It will restart your computer, and when you launch VS again, it will display more options on the screen, including Register / Sign in. Sign in using your Microsoft account here. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Well, I just removed the VS2013 and downloaded the VS2015 CE instead.

Comment: You needed to register your VS 2013 Community Edition within the first 30 days to obtain a permanent license, so just remember to do that with 2015 this time around. :)

Comment: I did that. It was just that I haven't used it for quite awhile. Then when I opened it the other day, this is what happened. So I'm guessing that you always have to open it and login to your account for it to stay active. Otherwise, you'll have a HUGE problem if you have lots of apps created in VS 2013.